# How can one use startWatchApp() while the parent iPhone app is in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos

How can somebody open an Apple Watch app using Swift, assuming the parent iPhone app is running in the background, without getting the below error?

```
Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=550 "Cannot start watch app when phone app is in background" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot start watch app when phone app is in background}
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?  You can't start the watch app when your app is in the background; this would be a bad user experience since the watch would suddenly do something without the user expecting it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The error message clearly states that this is something the API intends to prevent you from doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can not start from companion iOS App when it's inactive, it's strictly prohibited by Apple. But you can check for other options like scheduling a ExtendedRunTimeSession in WatchOS App. You can inform the Watch from companion to schedule a trigger less than 36 hours. In this way you can tweak your functionality. This is just another alternative well depends on your use case may be possible not so sure.

Please not that this scheduling also should be happening when the WatchOS App is in Active state. But once its scheduled it can trigger at the time even though the WatchOS App is Inactive or in background.

Please check the following link for more information:-
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions